# Decode BCryptPassword to set in JavaMailSenderImpl

Tags: java, jakarta-mail, bcrypt, password-encryption

I have a password stored in a table. It is encoded with BCryptPasswordEncoder. When i try to set that password in JavaMailSenderImpl

```
Optional<EmailId> emailIdOptional = 
emailIdRepository.findByEmailId(emailMessage.getFromAddress());
JavaMailSenderImpl mailSender = new JavaMailSenderImpl();
mailSender.setHost("smtp.gmail.com");
mailSender.setPort(Integer.valueOf("587"));
mailSender.setUsername(emailIdOptional.get().getEmailId());
mailSender.setPassword(emailIdOptional.get().getPassword());
```

But when i try to send a mail using this mailSender i got MailAuthenticationException

> org.springframework.mail.MailAuthenticationException: Authentication failed; nested exception is javax.mail.AuthenticationFailedException

Can we decode the BCrypt Password?
How can we match the BCrypt password in javamailsender?

Comment: You don't. The entire point of BCrypt is that you can't get the password back after it's encoded.

Comment: Then how can we use encrypted password to match in JavaMailSenderImpl ?

Comment: It's not *encrypted*, it's *hashed*. You have to separately store the password in some recoverable form, which is generally not a great idea in the first place (why is this program supposed to know everyone's Gmail password?).

Comment: Unless you control your own mail server, you're not going to be able to impersonate other users.  Why do you think you need to send email that looks like it came from someone else?

Comment: @chrylis This is a scheduled email. The mails would be sent to destinations from different email ids in different days. Its not practicable to ask the mail password every time when mail is sending as it is a scheduled one.

Comment: You're going to need to [use OAuth authentication with Gmail](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/auth/about-auth).